# 2048x2032 Raw image data size?

Tags: c, image, ram

I need to dump a 24 bit Raw image straight out of ram into a file but I keep on getting way to much trash data that comes after wards. So id like to calculate my parameters to try and dump literally only the image...The block of ram will be allocated for only the image so there fore it will always start where my pointer starts.
So I thought that because the `WRITE()` (in C) function works with the size of bytes that this calculation im doing here will help me out. BUT im new to the entire Image data so im not quite sure if its 100% and also 12Meg per image seems a bit small.

Is it right to assume that in a **2048x2032 (24bit)** raw image that the total pixel count will be

```
2048x2032 =  4161536*24     = 99876864/8 =   12484608 ?
          (bits per pixel)     (bytes)     (bytes in total)
```

Comment: your calculations are correct provided that this is 24 bits (3 bytes) per pixel.

Comment: @Mansuro for the nice format :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thats correct.

However, you should be aware that some images have "padding" at the end of each line, meaning a line could be 2048*24 bits plus a few bytes long, in theory.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation is correct as to how many bits of the image contain actual data. But the actual file size depends on the pixel format. There are tons of those:

- RGB (1 byte == 1 color)
- 32bit RGB (1 32 bit int == 1 pixel, 8 bits are wasted or used for an alpha channel)
- 32bit RGBA (3x8 bit color + 8bit alpha channel)
- 16bit color RGB (16bit per color)

just to name a few.